# MixColumn AES manually with GF(2^8)

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

In the step of MixColumn in AES, calculate d0,0 if given c0,0 = c2,0 =
1100 0101, and c1,0 = c3,0 = 0100 1100.

**Converting to polynomials:**

c0,0 = c2,0 = x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + 1
c1,0 = c3,0 = x^6 + x^3 + x^2

now using the Galois field to get d0,0 we will get 4 results and then XOR all of them

c0,0 * 10 = (x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + 1)*(x) mod (x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) mod 2 = 10010001

c1,0 * 11 = (x^6 + x^3 + x^2) * (x+1) mod (x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) mod 2 = 11100100

c2,0 * 01 = (x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + 1)*(1) mod (x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) mod 2 = 11000101

c3,0 * 01 = (x^6 + x^3 + x^2) * (1) mod (x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) mod 2 = 01001100

**Now XOR all of those 8 bit binary values I get 11111100 but the answer should be 11001100 where am I making my mistake?**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Should the last product be $c_{3,0}\cdot01$? The stuff to the right of the first equality sign suggests that the multiplier is $1$, only on the left hand side you typed $c_{3,0}\cdot11$?

Comment: Yes you are correct I will make the edit. and as you suggested in your answer I gave you the upvote and the checkmark. My issue was with c2,0 * 01 I thought you would overflow the 2x^3 component.

Comment: I see. Modulo $2$ kills the $2x^3$ term. The coefficients of powers of $x$ are to be treated modulo $2$, so $\overline{2x^3}=\overline{0x^3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second product is incorrect. There is no overflow to degree $8$ in that product, and it comes out as
$$
\begin{aligned}
c_{1,0}\cdot 11&=\overline{(x^6+x^3+x^2)(x+1)}\\
&=\overline{x^7+x^6+x^4+2x^3+x^2}\\
&=\overline{x^7+x^6+x^4+x^2}=11010100.
\end{aligned}
$$
I use overline to denote the coset of a polynomial because iterated mods give me pimples.
Anyway, this differs exactly in those two bit positions your end result differs from the given answer, so I'm optimistic about it being the only error.

Comment: Thank you so much I was concerned that my overall approach was incorrect I appreciate the guidance I also like your way of dealing with the iterated mods